# Pass a file opened in a function to another function to analyze it in python

Tags: python

I'm using a function to let my user open a file by clicking a button.

```
def open():
    global img
    file = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes =(("Text File", "*.txt"),("All Files","*.*")), title = "Select")
    txt = []    
    with open(file, "r", encoding='utf-8') as f:          
    [...]
    outputData = pd.DataFrame(txt)
    return txt
```

After that by pressing another button should also start some analysis using pandas, but How can I use the dataframe I create in this below function?

```
def analyze():  
    total = len(outputData)
```

This is the error I'm getting: "Error: NameError: name 'outputData' is not defined"
After someone click the analysis button I'd like also to display the result in the "total_label" so that it can be seen by my user.

```
sel_btn = Button(frame, command=open)
an_btn = Button(frame, command=analyze)
total_label = Label(frame, textvariable='total')
sel_btn.pack()
an_btn.pack()
total_label.pack()
```

Thank you!

**EDIT**
I'm still getting some error, this one: "TypeError: analyze_chat() missing 1 required positional argument: 'outputData'"

This is my full code

```
def open():
    global img
    file = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes =(("Text File", "*.txt"),("All Files","*.*")), title = "Select Chat")
    txt = []    
    exclude_string = "Tap for more info."
    with open(file, "r", encoding='utf-8') as f:
            for line in f:
                lines = line.split(' - ')  # Divide between date and the rest
                if len(lines) > 1:
                    if not lines[1].__contains__(exclude_string):
                        lines2 = lines[1].split(': ')  # Divide between user and text
                        if len(lines2) > 1:
                            sender = lines2[0]
                            text = lines2[1]
                            time = lines[0]
                            txt += [[time, sender, text]]

    

    outputData = pd.DataFrame(txt, columns=['datetime', 'sender', 'text'])  
    outputData.to_csv('output2.csv', index=False, line_terminator='\n', encoding='utf-8')

    analyze(outputData) 

    select_btn['command']=0
    select_btn.config(image=step1_2_img, relief=SUNKEN)
    analyze_btn.config(image=step2_2_img)   

    return txt


def analyze(outputData):    
    total = len(outputData)
```

Comment: Because your error is referencing `analyze_chat` which is not in your code, I'm assuming that this isn't absolutely everything, have you checked to see if `analyze_chat` has the required argument?

Comment: Change your label text by doing this `total_label.config(text=analysis)`

Answer (score 0):

```
def open():
   [code_here]
   outputData = pd.DataFrame(txt)
   analyze(outputData) #this basically passes the variable to the function
```

and in the analyze function

```
def analyze(outputData):
   total = len(outputData)
```

so for an easier understanding

```
def first():
   passme = 'text'
   second(passme)
def second(passme):
   print(passme)
```

That would print **text** in the **second** function

The variable gets passed and called

Hope this helps, im learning too

**EDIT**
Turn the below code

```
    analyze(outputData) 

    select_btn['command']=0
    select_btn.config(image=step1_2_img, relief=SUNKEN)
    analyze_btn.config(image=step2_2_img)   

    return txt
```

into

```
    select_btn['command']=0
    select_btn.config(image=step1_2_img, relief=SUNKEN)
    analyze_btn.config(image=step2_2_img) 
  
    return txt
    analyze(outputData)
```

or

```
    select_btn['command']=0
    select_btn.config(image=step1_2_img, relief=SUNKEN)
    analyze_btn.config(image=step2_2_img)   

    analyze(outputData, txt)

    def analyze(outputData, txt):
    [YOUR CODE HERE]
```

Comment: NB: teaching about passing stuff through functions

Comment: Thank you, I've tried you solution. But I'm still getting an error. I editated my question hopefully it would be easier to see what I'm doing wrong

Comment: youre currently getting "TypeError: analyze_chat() missing 1 required positional argument: 'outputData'" because youre not passing outputData to **analyze_chat()**

Comment: try putting ```analyze(outputData)``` below ```return txt```

Comment: @DianaMele check my answer again and try that and if that doesnt work try removing the ```return txt``` then changing ```analyze(outputData)``` to ```analyze(outputData, txt)``` then adding ```txt``` to ```def analyze(outputData):``` like ```def analyze(outputData, txt):```

Comment: I've tried but way but it just keep giving me back the error that Analyze is missing required positional arguments

Comment: press ctrl + F then search for ```analyze_chat()``` then delete it and see if it works? yeah ive been wasting time on ```analyze()``` while ignoring ```analyze_chat()```, if deleting ```analyze_chat()``` didnt work then make it ```analyze_chat(outputData)```

Comment: also in the code above, you dont mention any analyze_chat() apart from the error coming from analyze_chat()

Comment: because i ran the code on my python, and so far i havent received any errors apart from the select_btns, but probably because i dont have the full code or something, but nothing to do with **analyze_chat()**